# My problem is when I press the clear button, it just clears the textfield and not data of the previous numbers pressed

Tags: java, swing, awt

The task here is to make a Java program that is like a pincode process. I just have a problem with the process of clearing since when I press the clear button, it actually clears the textfield but when I press new numbers, the numbers I typed before even after pressing clear still shows up

```
enter code here
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Pincode extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
JLabel display, displayExtra;
JButton numButton;
JButton clr;
JButton etr;
String displayContent = "";
String[] numPadContent = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "CLEAR", "0", "ENTER"};
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;
String PASSWORD = "061904";
Pincode(Container pane) {
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 335));
    display = new JLabel(displayContent);
    displayExtra = new JLabel(displayContent);
    display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 25));
    display.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    pane.add(display, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>(12);
    JPanel numberPanel = new JPanel();
    numberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 0, 0));
    numberPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 260));
    for (int i = 0; i < numPadContent.length; i++) {
        numButton = new JButton(numPadContent[i]);
        buttonList.add(numButton);
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < buttonList.size(); n++) {
        buttonList.get(n).addActionListener(this);
        numberPanel.add(buttonList.get(n));
    }
    pane.add(numberPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    clr = new JButton("Clear");
    clr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 30));
    clr.addActionListener(this);
    etr = new JButton("Enter");
    etr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 30));
    etr.addActionListener(this);
    pane.add(clr);
    pane.add(etr);
}
public void Authorized(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are authorized");
}
public void Unauthorized(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are not authorized!!!");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String textThere = display.getText(), textThereExtra = displayExtra.getText();
    String additionalText = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < buttonList.size(); a++) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(a)) && a!=11 && a!=9) {
            additionalText = buttonList.get(a).getText();
        }
    }
    int flag = 0;
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(9))) {
        textThere = "";
        textThereExtra = "";
        flag = 1;
    }
    if(flag != 1) {
        display.setText(textThere.concat("*"));
        displayExtra.setText(textThereExtra.concat(additionalText));
    }
    else
        display.setText(textThere);

    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(11))) {
        System.out.println(textThereExtra);
        System.out.println(textThere);
        if(textThereExtra.equals(PASSWORD)) {
            Authorized();
        }
        else {
            Unauthorized();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Pincode(frame));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Please help me with my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: My problem now is how do you show the exact number of asterisk on the textfield to how many numbers were pressed and not add an additional asterisk? Because it keeps on adding another asterisk on the textfield whenever I press the enter button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to update the JLabel text for displayExtra.
Just add `displayExtra.setText(textThereExtra);` in the else block where you ask if flag != 1 and you should be good to go!

Comment: My problem now is how do you show the exact number of asterisk on the textfield to how many numbers were pressed and not add an additional asterisk? Because it keeps on adding another asterisk on the textfield whenever I press the enter button.

Comment: *"My problem now"* The original problem was *"..when I press the clear button, it just clears the textfield and not data of the previous numbers pressed"* which this answer seems to have solved. If you have a new question, start a new thread to ask it. In the meantime, I am about to roll the last edit back. Please accept this answer by clicking the small tick to the left of it.

Comment: I already did, do I post another thread for my question?